# Runnable Jar isn't creating HTML page like eclipse

Tags: java

When I export my runnable Jar file and run it, it creates the HTML page but it is blank. When I run it on eclipse the html page created and contains all the text that I output in the application.

Why is this happening? My assumption is creating the Jar file changes my path and so the paths I define within my code lead to nothing.

Comment: Your assumption is likely correct. However, without sample code, we can only guess at what the problem may be.

Comment: @SnakeDoc is right. Have you tried using Chrome's Developer tools (Right Click > Inspect) or similar and seeing whether there are any obvious errors being thrown as well?

Comment: @SnakeDoc ...or have you simply had a look at the content of your blank page. You probably couldn't see if there is a stack trace in the `head`section otherwise,

Comment: Are you using Swing?  It could be that you have a thread conflict.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: It's far more likely the OP has some hard-coded paths which work in Eclipse (which treats absolute paths differently than one would expect in a JAR file). If OP is bundling resources into the JAR, they should be using the traditional `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`